# Find all natural sequences $a_n=a_{a_{n-1}}+a_{a_{n+1}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

Find all natural sequences for which holds $$a_n=a_{a_{n-1}}+a_{a_{n+1}}$$

a) for all natural numbers $n\ge 2$

b) for all natural numbers $n\ge 3$

I tried to do something with the characteristic equation but nothing good comes out of it...
Its really my first time to see such a kind of a problem

We have that $a_n> a_{a_{n+1}}$. So it seems like it is constantly decreasing so at one point it should get constant.

Comment: The function f(x)=x/2 works, but not for natural numbers.

Comment: We have $a_{n+1}=a_n - a_{n-1}$, so once you fix the first two terms of the sequence, you fix the entire sequence. The question reduces to finding all $a_0, a_1$ such that the entire sequence consists of natural numbers.

Comment: @Jack M Its $a_{a_{n+1}}=...$ and not $a_{n+1}$

Comment: @SoulEater Oh, well that's much more interesting.

Answer (score 1):

For question b), there is 1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2...

Comment: My teacher said that that is the only solution. a) has no solution and b) has only that as a solution

Comment: Well there is also $0,~ 0 ,~ 0 ,~ 0 ,~ \dots$ isn't there?

Comment: @DanielV: Depends on if $0\in\mathbb{N}$ or not. I think OP or OP's teacher should clearify.

Comment: Well almost no properties of sequence $a$ were specified at all.  We could be talking about matrices or elephants or anything.

Comment: @DanielV: True, I erroneously read "natural sequence" as "sequence of natural numbers".